# List Impala tables that need invalidate/refresh

Tags: impala

How can I programatically find all Impala tables that need `INVALIDATE METADATA` statement (because they were created in Hive, but not yet known to Impala) or `REFRESH` (because column added, datafile added, etc.)?

Comment: Good question. That would greatly improve the life of all people forced to use Impala because their CIO bought Cloudera licenses in 2015 (Cloudera Manager was a deal-maker then). But I'm pessimistic.

Comment: Note that `beeline` has an option to "INVALIDATE METADATA" globally at connect time. That's a hint that Cloudera has no idea how to incrementally invalidate their metadata cache ; otherwise the Catalog would do it in the background _(just like Sentry incrementally resets HDFS ACLs by brute force every 5 minutes, due to the infamous HDFS bug in Hadoop 2.x)_

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter - you mean `impala-shell` and `--refresh_after_connect` option, not `beeline`, right?

Comment: Oops, yes indeed.

Comment: --refresh_after_connect option is removed starting from impala 3.0. It was deprecated from 2.11 apparently. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-3998

Answer (score 0):

**Invalidate Metadata:**

As a workaround, create a shell script to do the below steps.

1. Using beeline, connect to a particular database and run show tables statement and save output data to a file.
2. Using impala-shell, connect to the same particular database and run show tables statement and save output data to another file.
3. Now compare both the file to remove the duplicates and get the unique tables list from the first file which is a list of tables which are only in hive but not in impala.

Note:

a. Instead of a particular database each at a time in 1 and 2 steps, you can loop over all databases and save the output to a file. Inside the loop itself, you can redirect and append the output files to another final output file with data in some format like database.table or database_table to get all tables from all databases into a single file. Finally, follow step 3.

b. The unique tables from the second output file after removing duplicates will be tables that are deleted in hive and invalidate metadata needs to be run in impala to remove them from the impala list.

c. Rename of a table in impala can be recognized by hive but vice-versa is not possible and invalidate metadata should be run for both old and new table names to remove and add respectively in impala. This applies to most operations not just rename of table.

**Refresh:**

Consider a text format table with 2 columns and 1 row data.
Now suppose, a third column is added to that table in the beeline.

```
select * from table; ---gives 3 columns in beeline and 2 columns in impala since refresh is not run on impala for this table.
```

If we run compute stats in impala before running refresh in this case, then that newly added column from the beeline will be removed from the table schema in hive as well.

```
select * from table; ---gives 2 columns in beeline and 2 columns in impala since compute stats from impala deleted the extra column metadata of table although data resides in hdfs for that column. This might cause parsing issues in impala if the column is added somewhere in the middle or front instead of ending.
```

So it is advised to run REFRESH table name in impala right after adding a new column or doing any modifications in beeline for an existing table to not lose table schema as explained in the above scenario.

```
refresh table; ---Right after modification in hive run refresh in impala.

select * from table; ---gives 3 columns in beeline and 3 columns in impala since refresh is run before compute stats in impala.
```